# Is `row.names = "Geneid"` calling for a variable called Geneid or is it attempting to assign it?

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and still attempting to get my head around the language.
I have been given an example script & I am attempting to adapt it for my analysis. I am trying to read the output using the code

```
counts=read.csv("mydata", sep="", head=T, row.names = "Geneid")
```

However, I am getting the error message

```
Error in data[[rowvar]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

When trying to run this. When searching this error code I come to the conclusion that this is likely because I am calling for a variable that does not exist within this dataset.
Does `row.names = "Geneid` call for the variable Geneid or does it assign it to the rows?

I am just trying to gain a better understanding of R and the language behind it.

Comment: `read.csv` is looking for a column called `Geneid`, and you will get an error if the column does not exist in your csv file. Row names are rarely used in modern R. If the row names contains useful information they should be in their own proper column, and if they don't, we just let R give them the default names, which are just plain row numbers. If your data set doesn't have a `Geneid` column,  just leave out the `row.names` argument altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```r
?read.csv
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> `row.names`
> a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the actual row
> names,  or a single number giving the column of the table which
> contains the row names, or character string giving the name of the
> table column containing the row names.